# Why I can not peek Ipv4Header from a packet in in INET by calling peekAtFront method?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I wanted to peek Ipv4Header from a packet, but the system thrown a runtime error as following:

> <!> Returning an incomplete chunk is not allowed according to the flags: 0 -- in module (inet::ieee80211::Dcf)

The line of code causing error is:

```
const auto& ipv4header = packet->peekAtFront<Ipv4Header>();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you edit your question and write in what module that code is used?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are trying to get an Ipv4Header at the **link layer** (802.11 Dcf). That is not possible. Nobody have ever guarantied that a link layer data packet starts with an IP header. IP packets can (and will) be fragmented if the MTU is smaller than the actual packet size. The first fragment indeed will start with an IP header, but subsequent fragments definitely will NOT.

As a general rule of thumb, if you are trying to access an upper OSI level data structure in a lower OSI level, you are definitely **doing it wrong**.